# create vector of dates excluding weekends

Tags: matlab, date, weekday

I am trying to create a vector of daily dates. I however do not want to include the weeknds (i.e. Saturdays or Sundays.

I am using the isbusday function which nearly does what I require. In that no Saturdays or Sundays are returns in my date_vector ('date_vec'). However it also removed US bank holidays so for example in my date vector there are no 25th December's. Is there a way to force this method to ignore bank holidays or should I be using another method altogether?

```
date_vec = [dt_start : dt_end];           % daily dates
weekend_vec = [1 0 0 0 0 0 1];            % vector to help remove weekends
bus_day = isbusday(date_vec, [], weekend_vec);
date_vec(bus_day == 0) = [];
```

**Matlab function ISBUSDAY**

```
%ISBUSDAY True for dates that are business days.
%
% T = ISBUSDAY(Date, Holiday, Weekend)
%
% Inputs:
%        
%   Date    - a vector of dates in question.  Dates are assumed to be whole
%             date numbers or date stamps with no fractional or time
%             values.
%
% Optional Inputs:
%
%   Holiday - a user-defined vector of holidays. The default
%             is a predefined US holidays (in holidays.m)
%
%   Weekend - a vector of length 7, containing 0 and 1, with
%             the value of 1 to indicate weekend day(s). 
%             The first element of this vector corresponds 
%             to Sunday. 
%             Thus, when Saturday and Sunday are weekend
%             then WEEKEND = [1 0 0 0 0 0 1]. The default
%             is Saturday and Sunday weekend.
```

Comment: Please post a runnable example: define `dt_start` etc

Comment: Try `mod(date_vec, 7)`, you should find that this will assign a unique number (0-6) for each day of  the week. Then you can just filter the weekends like filtering a number.

Comment: would weekday function work? http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/weekday.html something like ismember(weekday(date_vec), 2:6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [`isbusday` documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/finance/isbusday.html), if the second argument is `[]` it uses *default* holidays. To force `isbusday` to *not* consider holidays at all, use as a second argument a value out of your range, such as serial date `0`:

```
bus_day = isbusday(date_vec, 0, weekend_vec);
```